# "close project" decorator doesn't update until restart of eclipse (Windows only)

Tags: eclipse, project, pydev, decorator

In pydev package explorer (Eclipse Indigo) when I right click and select "close project" the icon does not show the closed decorator. Only when I restart eclipse will it then be properly refreshed and show a closed decorator (solid blue folder).

This only happens for windows. On my mac the close project works correctly.

This is just general bug reporting - obviously I am not losing sleep over this!

Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149

Pydev 2.3.0.20111221518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be already fixed in the latest nightly build :)

Comment: I think you can just mark it as accepted -- so, if someone does have that issue from an old version they can find the answer and upgrade :)